# Any example for sulu 2.x under kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, sulu

I'm in trouble having sulu 2.x working in kubernetes.

There is an example for sulu 1.4 [here](https://github.com/sulu/k8s-example-deployment/pull/1/files) but there are some 1.4 specificities.

I'm wondering if their is any example for sulu 2.x ?
If not, any recommendations?

Comment: The repository and PR you mentioned is build for 2.x version of sulu afaik its currently sulu 2.1 but that does not matter.

I am currently trying to update the newest chart version and that will follow as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the PR https://github.com/sulu/k8s-example-deployment/pull/1 to use the newest sulu chart and allow Kubernetes 1.19 - see the updated docs in the readme